# Не работает переменожение матриц в math.js

Tags: javascript, математика

На codepen подключил math.js. Пример с их сайта работает, но мой почему-то нет. Также пробовал заменять multiply на dotMultiply.

```
var i =[
  [0.9],
  [0.1],
  [0.8]
];
var w =[
  [0.9,0.3,0.4],
  [0.2,0.8,0.2],
  [0.1,0.5,0.6]
];
alert(math.multiply(i,w));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не совпадает количество слолбцбов в первой матрице и строк во второй.

Вы имеете: 1 столбец в первой матрице и 3 строки во второй матрице.

Согласно правилу умножению матриц, количество слобцов левой матрицы и количество строк правой матрицы должны быть равны.

Возможно, вам нужно исправить первую матрицу так:

```
var i =[
  [0.9, 0.1, 0.8]
];
var w =[
  [0.9,0.3,0.4],
  [0.2,0.8,0.2],
  [0.1,0.5,0.6]
];
alert(math.multiply(i,w));
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло